# In vb asp.net I'm unable to obtain the selected TreeView node

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

The problem I'm having is: when a node is clicked, the selected node index is always -1 and the selected node text is always the text of the first node.
As you can see in the code below, I've created a test-app. This test-app shows the same problem

This is my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Treeviewer._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TreeView ID="tvDir" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvDir_SelectedNodeChanged" OnTreeNodeExpanded="tvDir_TreeNodeExpanded" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code-behind:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        tvDir.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("C:\"))
        For Each aDir As String In IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\")
            Dim aNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(aDir, 0)
            If hasSubDirectories(aDir) Then
                aNode.ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode("", 1))
            End If
            aNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
            tvDir.Nodes(0).ChildNodes.Add(aNode)
        Next
        tvDir.CollapseAll()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub tvDir_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim tvIndex = tvDir.Nodes.IndexOf(tvDir.SelectedNode)
        Debug.Write(tvIndex & " " & tvDir.SelectedNode.Text)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub tvDir_TreeNodeExpanded(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeEventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Function hasSubDirectories(inDirectory As String) As Boolean
        Try
            If IO.Directory.Exists(inDirectory) Then
                Return IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(inDirectory).Count > 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            '
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: it looks like you set the same `value` to all nodes of a level. `New TreeNode(aDir, 0)`

Comment: That's true. But, I expected the index to be correct and it's not: it's always -1. But, you are right. When I specify aDir as value also, I get the correct value. Thanks!